# The role of vocal vibrato in a world where volume and large theatres are not a problem

Tags: voice, voice-training, vibrato

I have had singing lessons for a while now. My teacher has said on numerous occasions ‘don’t worry about your vibrato, it is fine’. I still have to work the technique don’t get me wrong, but it is there.

I can’t help but notice, naturally, other singers vibrato.

Some are very fast, it sounds like an engine, I think this sound is better to be honest, and some are more looped, like you can hear the actual *waves* within the vibrato pitch more clearly. Opera singers I have found tend to have this ability. To really make it sound as whole and as full as possible.

Everyone’s voice is different yes, but should all vibrato be the same? Is a quicker vibrato used for certain songs or styles? Likewise the other way round? *What is the goal for vocal vibrato in a modern world where volume and large amphitheatres are (broadly speaking) no longer a problem.*

Comment: I'm pretty sure vibrato is actually to make intonation sound better, not to sound louder.

Comment: I think, as Todd said, you are coming at this the wrong way. There is no goal with vibrato related to volume, and what type people use is up to them - this question may be closed as too broad / opinion based

Comment: Apart from differing types of vibrato - volume changes, timbre changes, and the worst, pitch changes, none make the voice more audible. Fast , medium, slow, some singers can vary their own vib., others have the one and get on with it, but as Todd and the Dr. say, this maybe isn't the question you are looking for the answer to.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't believe your teacher, it isn't likely you'll believe some strangers on a forum who never even heard you.

Vibrato is not an active technique but a *result* of a certain kind of relaxed vocal production.  It is not an "effect" to plan for but something that you accommodate eventually.  It is a *trait* of a voice surfacing under training.  One learns one's individual boundary conditions producing the best results for one's given voice for certain kinds of music.

So listen to your teacher: don't worry about vibrato.  If it comes around and makes a mess of your singing, you'll be working with your teacher to address it and learn to control it in a manner working with *your* voice.  If it's not there, it's premature and even counterproductive to worry about it.  It's usually more work for a trained voice to keep it in check rather than produce it in the first place, so actively trying to produce it when it's not there by itself is going to make you do things that are a bad idea.

Comment: +1 even for the 1st para!  Some people have natural vib., others have to strive for it. Some can control it, others...

Comment: ...always sound like someone's operating an asphalt-compaction rammer on their chest, @Tim?